# vba dynamic range issue

Tags: vba, excel

```
With newexcel.Sheets("Analysis")
    .Range("I1").AutoFilter Field:=9, Criteria1:="<>#N/A"
    .Range("E1").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="InActive"
    .Range("D1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=(BLANK)
    .AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy newexcel.Sheets("Test").Range("A1")
     firstRow139 = .AutoFilter.Range.Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Row
End With

With newexcel.Sheets("Analysis").Range(newexcel.Sheets("Analysis").Cells(firstRow139, 4), newexcel.Sheets("Analysis").Cells(lastRow139, 4))
    .Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A&firstRow139,'Test'!A:D,4,0)"
End With
```

Here in vlookup, it is not taking firstRow139 value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to take the variable `firstRow139` outside the `"` part of the formula.

Change your current formula like:

```
.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A&firstRow139,'Test'!A:D,4,0)"
```

to:

```
.Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A" & firstRow139 & ",'Test'!A:D,4,0)"
```

---

I might change the structue of how you use the `With` to:

```
With newexcel.Sheets("Analysis")
    .Range(.Cells(firstRow139, 4), .Cells(lastRow139, 4)).Formula = "=VLOOKUP(A" & firstRow139 & ",'Test'!A:D,4,0)"
End With
```